# DQN RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (18x7 and 126x64)

Tags: matrix, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, runtime-error

I am trying to implement the DQN algorithm using pytorch. My environment returns an observation that preprocesses it to a tensor of shape `torch.Size([1, 2, 9, 7])`. An example of the input:

```
tensor([[[[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1815, 0.2127, 0.2431, 0.3362, 0.3416],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1969, 0.2341],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.5838, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.4880, 0.7366, 0.7777, 0.7594]],

         [[0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1815, 0.2127, 0.2431, 0.3362, 0.3416],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.1969, 0.2341],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
          [0.5838, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.4880, 0.7366, 0.7777, 0.7594]]]])
```

I get the issue with shapes `RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (18x7 and 126x64)` after calling the act function of my neural net:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,  env:Env):
        super().__init__()
        self.env = env
        in_features = int(np.prod(env.observation_space.shape))
        self.sequen= nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, env.action_space.n) 
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.sequen(x)

    def act(self, obs):
        q_values = self(obs).to(device) ### the problem is here !!!!!
        max_q_index = torch.argmax(q_values, dim=1)[0]
        action = max_q_index.detach().item()
        return action
```

Although I understand that 18*7 = 126 which is the input dimension of the first linear layer, I do not know how to fix the problem.
Posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72724452/mat1-and-mat2-shapes-cannot-be-multiplied-128x4-and-128x64) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778174/runtime-error-mat1-and-mat2-shapes-cannot-be-multiplied-in-pytorch) helped to understand the problem but not how to solve it.

**UPDATE**
The following code seemed to solve the issue both when passing 1 and several observations.

```py
obs = obs.unsqueeze(0)
obs = obs.view(obs.shape[0], -1)
```

Comment: Is this solved or are you expecting any further help? If not, you just need to reshape it such that your input tensor of size `bx2x9x7` should be `bx128`, where b is batch size. You can look into use of flatten, see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html . `x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)` should do the job.

Comment: It solves the code issue but tbh I don't fully understand why it works simultaneously when passing a single observation and a batch of them

Comment: Its quite simple - nn.Linear is just matrix multiplication. Where you are multplying your input which is `b x 126` with model matrix of size `126 x 64`, this gives an intermediate output of `b x 64`. So whether b is 1, or b is 10 doesnt matter. For each sample in batch, i.e. `1 x 126` input sample, you get `1x64` output. Remember, axis=0 is your batch and axis=1 is your features. Now, your model is not just a single matrix multiplication, but matrix multiplication followed by Relu followed by another matrix multiplication. Relu doesnt change dimension, i.e. input size is same as output size.

Comment: Finally we have another matrix multiplication, where `b x 64` matrix is multiplied by `64 x env.action_space.n` giving final output of size `b x env.action_space.n`. I would recomend a deep learning course as well as how to debug in IDE (VSCode or Pycharm). The latter one is very helpful in understanding what the code does and ofcourse official documentation does too https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html

Comment: If this answers your question, let me know and I will post the answer.

Comment: @saurabheights you may put your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model uses `Linear-> ReLU -> Linear` architecture, where [nn.Linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) is just matrix multiplication layer. The first linear matrix is of size `126 x 64` and second linear matrix is of size `64 x env.action_space.n`.

Given 2 matrices A and B of size `mxn` and `pxq` respectively, for matrix multiplication between A and B, `n` should be equal to `p`. The issue is in dimension of input when passed for forward inference to the first layer. For matrix multiplication, your input tensor `x` of size `bx2x9x7` should be changed to `bx126` to match first linear matrix dimensions `126 x 64`, where `b` is batch size.

Solution:- use resize (more generic) or flatten to fix the tensor size.

```
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
```

**or**

```
x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
```